# stream from microphone, add effect and save to wav file using tarsos android library

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, tarsosdsp

Notes: I'm using android studio and currently I'm using the latest [tarsos audio library](http://0110.be/posts/TarsosDSP_on_Android_-_Audio_Processing_in_Java_on_Android) that is supposed to be compatible with android, and in fact have successfully added the library to my android studio project. I previously tried using the JTransforms and the Minim libraries with no luck.
EDITED 8/23/17: found and fixed some bugs, reposted current code, still made no progress with the actual problem summarized below:

Summary: in the 5th code block I have posted, on line 15 that is commented out, I need to know how to get that line to work and not throw a compile error

What I'm trying to do is record from the microphone, and while recording use the dsp BandPass filter from the tarsos library and output the results to a .wav file. I can successfully stream the microphone to a .wav file following [this tutorial](http://Audio%20Recording%20In%20.Wav%20Format%20In%20Android%20Programming%20-%20EDUmobile.ORG) by using the android.media imports, but that doesn't allow me to add the BandPass filter, and using the tarsos imports functions don't allow me to use the save as .wav methods that [that tutorial has](http://audio%20recording%20in%20.wav%20format%20in%20android%20programming%20-%20edumobile.org/), I know I'm missing something and/or doing something wrong, but I've been googling this for almost a week and haven't found a working solution, I've only found links to the java files that are inside the library which isn't helpful as I couldn't find tutorials on how to correctly use them. What am I doing wrong? Here is the relevant code for the tarsos method I'm trying to use:

the related imports and 'global' variables

```
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioTrack;

import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioDispatcher;
import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioProcessor;
import be.tarsos.dsp.filters.BandPass;
import be.tarsos.dsp.io.android.AudioDispatcherFactory;

//start the class 

AudioRecord alteredRecord = null;
AudioDispatcher dispatcher;
float freqChange;
float tollerance;
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "Crowd_Speech";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int bufferSize = 1024;
private Thread recordingThread = null;

//set the min buffer size in onCreate event
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 
RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)*4;
```

This starts the mic recording inside an onClick method, and by commenting/uncommenting one of the 2 'running' variable values I can switch between filter or no filter (android or tarsos functions) when the startRecording method is called

```
if(crowdFilter && running==0 && set==0){//crowd speech mode, start talking
    Icons(2,"");
    running=4;//start recording from mic, apply bandpass filter and save as wave file using TARSOS import
    //running=5;//start recording from mic, no filter, save as wav file using android media import
    freqChange = Globals.minFr[Globals.curUser];
    tollerance = 40;
    set=1;
    startRecording();
}
```

The start recording method:

```
private void startRecording() {

    if (running == 5) {//start recording from mic, no filter, save as wav file using android media library
        alteredRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
            alteredRecord.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
                }
            }, "Crowd_Speech Thread");
            recordingThread.start();
    }

    if (running == 4) {//start recording from mic, apply bandpass filter and save as wave file using TARSOS library
        dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, bufferSize, 0);
        AudioProcessor p = new BandPass(freqChange, tollerance, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(p);
            isRecording = true;
            dispatcher.run();
            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
                }
            }, "Crowd_Speech Thread");
            recordingThread.start();
    }
}
```

Stop recording button inside an onClick method

```
if(crowdFilter && (running==4 || running==5) && set==0) {//crowd speech finished talking
    Icons(1, "");
    stopRecording();
    set = 1;
}
```

Both cases are fine until this point, if running==4 (tarsos dsp filter applied) the program crashes. if I use running==5 (the android.media way with no filter) the whole rest of this works fine and saves the file, but no BandPass effect applied. if I try swapping out the alteredRecord = new AudioRecord... with the tarsos dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory... ( such as dispatcher = new AudioRecord...) they are incompatible and will not even think of compiling. (That's why line 15 in the following method is commented out)

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int read = 0;
    if(null != os){
        while(isRecording){
            if(running==4)
            {
                //read = dispatcher.(data, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            if(running==5)
            {
                read = alteredRecord.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRecording(){
    if(null != alteredRecord) {
        isRecording = false;
        int i = alteredRecord.getState();
        if (i == 1) {
            running = 0;
            alteredRecord.stop();
            alteredRecord.release();
            alteredRecord = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }
    }
        if(null !=dispatcher){
            isRecording = false;
            running = 0;
            dispatcher.stop();
            recordingThread = null;
        }
    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
    deleteTempFile();
}

private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());
    file.delete();
}

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 1;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;
    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);
        while(in.read(data) != -1){
            out.write(data);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {
    byte[] header = new byte[44];
    header[0] = 'R';header[1] = 'I'; header[2] = 'F';header[3] = 'F';// RIFF/WAVE header
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';header[9] = 'A';header[10] = 'V';header[11] = 'E';header[12] = 'f';header[13] = 'm';header[14] = 't';header[15] = ' ';// 'fmt ' chunk
    header[16] = 16;header[17] = 0;header[18] = 0;header[19] = 0;// 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[20] = 1;header[21] = 0;header[22] = (byte) channels;header[23] = 0;// format = 1
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff); header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);header[33] = 0;// block align
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;header[35] = 0;header[36] = 'd';header[37] = 'a';header[38] = 't';header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);// bits per sample
    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved, you need to use the writer function, and not bother with any of the methods needed to save a wav file from the android.media import functions, this is the working code segment from the startRecording method I changed:

```
if (running == 4) {//start recording from mic, apply bandpass filter and save as wave file using TARSOS library
        dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, bufferSize, 0);
        AudioProcessor p = new BandPass(freqChange, tollerance, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(p);
        isRecording = true;
        // Output
        RandomAccessFile outputFile = new RandomAccessFile(getFilename(), "rw");
        TarsosDSPAudioFormat outputFormat = new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, false);
        WriterProcessor writer = new WriterProcessor(outputFormat, outputFile);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer);
        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dispatcher.run();
            }
        }, "Crowd_Speech Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: I have used your code for recording but i m hearing noise in recorded file Please let us know your response  @Wraithious