# Tarsos WriterProcessor produces no output content

Tags: android, audio, tarsosdsp

I can't write a file when using WriterProcessor provided by Tarsos. The file exists, and no error is shown. But the file is empty, when I play it, there is no sound.

```
    final Float srf = 44100.0F;

    dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(mRecordFile.getPath(), srf.intValue(), bufferSize, 0);

    mOutputLowFile = new File(v.getContext().getFilesDir(), mOutputLowFileName);
    RandomAccessFile outputFile = null;
    try {
        outputFile = new RandomAccessFile( mOutputLowFile, "rw");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onFFT: FileNotFoundException: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TarsosDSPAudioFormat outputFormat = new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, false);
    WriterProcessor writer = new WriterProcessor(outputFormat, outputFile);

    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer);

    final AudioDispatcher finalDispatcher1 = dispatcher;
    Thread recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalDispatcher1.run();
        }
    }, "recordingThread Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
```

The outputFile is 1Ko big, whereas the original is 3 Ko.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I'm using and it works - in the pipeline I put also a PitchProcessor (this code comes mostly from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867328/4872992):

```
dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(SAMPLE_RATE, 1024, 0);
    AudioProcessor p = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(p);
    filePath = "/sdcard/recording_test.pcm";
    RandomAccessFile outputFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
    TarsosDSPAudioFormat outputFormat = new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);
    WriterProcessor writer = new WriterProcessor(outputFormat, outputFile);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer);
    recordingThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Dispatcher)");
    recordingThread.start();
```